# RSpec Can Only See Classes in the Root of my Lib Directory

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, specs

RSpec (2.12.2) is giving me a hard time. If I want to reference a class in one of my specs and that class is not in the root of my `/lib` directory, it throws an error:

```
no such file to load -- test (LoadError)
```

It seems that my specs can be nested in a folder structure, but the moment I try and require a class that is in a nested folder (for example `lib/workers/conversion_worker.rb`), I get this error.

I am using require 'spec_helper' in all my specs, but even hard-coding the path the classes results in the same error.

With this structure:

```
-lib/
  - class_found.rb
  - workers/
     - class_not_found.rb
```

The spec looks like this:

```
# spec/workers/class_not_found_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"
require "class_not_found"

describe ClassNotFound do    
  it "Does something"
end
```

The following runs the spec successfully (the -I flag adds a path to the $LOAD_PATH):

```
$ rspec spec/workers/class_not_found_spec.rb -I /Path/to/project/*
```

So it seems that RSpec isn't adding anything below lib to its path.

I can successfully require class_not_found.rb using require_relative:

```
require_relative "../../lib/workers/class_not_found.rb" #Succeeds
```

But not using require:

```
require "lib/workers/class_not_found.rb" # Fails
```

Comment: so you create a file named `spec/lib/workers/class_not_found_spec.rb`, write into `require 'spec_helper'; module Workers; describe ClassNotFound do ... end; end`, and rspec does not find the source?

Comment: @ProGNOMmers I've updated the question. Hopefully now it's clear.

Comment: is your project a rails app? if it is, you should move `spec/workers` to `spec/lib/workers`

Comment: @ProGNOMmers It's a Sinatra app.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: `require 'workers/class_not_found'` (without `lib`) works here

Comment: @ProGNOMmers Thanks for trying. I'm stumped.

Comment: try to put a `puts $LOAD_PATH.inspect` at the beginning of `spec/workers/class_not_found_spec.rb`, and ensure that `path/to/project/lib` is in the list

Comment: As someone else said in another question yesterday - rspec-core is v2.12.2, rspec is v2.12.0, they’re different gems, be careful not to confuse them.

Comment: I don't mean to seem facetious or anything like that, but since `require_relative` works, what's the problem?

Comment: try `require "./lib/workers/class_not_found.rb"` in ruby > 1.9 you need ./

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if you have an answer you like yet, but it seems like you aren't requiring your files correctly.

Your `'lib/class_found.rb'` file should require all your library files, so it should look something like:

```
require 'workers/class_not_found'
```

and your `spec_helper.rb` will require the main file in your `lib` folder, so it should look something like:

```
require 'class_found'
```

rspec automatically loads `'spec/spec_helper.rb'` when it runs, it also automatically adds the `'lib'` folder to its `LOAD_PATH`, so that your requires in `'lib/class_found.rb'` are seen and required properly.

Comment: Thanks Raj. Yes I had worked it out, but your answer is correct. It seems that lib is added, but subfolders of lib are not, so anything in a subfolder needs a path based on lib as well as a filename. Was a stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: I don't know if it's a stupid mistake.  I think this is an oddity that is just unexpected.  There's no good way to just say "include all the files in lib and subfolders".

Answer (score 0):

According to your directory tree, the file `class_not_found.rb` is in a subdirectory `workers`. You forgot to add the path to your `require`:

```
require 'workers/class_not_found'
```

would be correct.

By the way: you don't `require` classes, you `require` *files*.

Comment: Sorry. Bad semantics. Adding the path doesn't work, and RSpec is supposed to allow for filenames without paths as far as I know.

Comment: `require` has nothing to do with RSpec. `require` is a plain Ruby method from the Ruby core library. It searches the `$LOAD_PATH`. Nothing more, nothing less.